# Why do javascript objects output as "undefined" when looping through an array?

Tags: javascript

You can see a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bwhitney/ZDHp4/1/

I am trying to create an array of objects in javascript. When I attempt to access the objects I am getting "undefined" output. Here is some sample code:

```
var dates = [];

var beginDate1 = new Date("01 / 01 / 01");
var endDate1 = new Date("02 / 02 / 02");
var beginDate2 = new Date("03 / 03 / 03");
var endDate2 = new Date("04 / 04 / 04");

// this outputs the correct dates
alert("before: " + beginDate1 + "--" + endDate1);
alert("before: " + beginDate2 + "--" + endDate2);

dates.push({
    "beginDate": beginDate1,
    "endDate": endDate1
}, {
    "beginDate": beginDate2,
    "endDate": endDate2
});

var date;
for (date in dates) {
    // this outputs "date: undefined--undefined"
    // why would that be?
    alert("after: " + date.beginDate + "--" + date.endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for ... in` loop in JavaScript gives you the **keys** in the object, not the values.

You really should use a numeric index however:

```
for (var date = 0; date < dates.length; ++date) {
  alert("date " + date + " is: " + dates[date]);
}
```

Iterating over keys with `for ... in` will not pick up only the numerically-indexed array elements; it operates on arrays as if they are plain ordinary objects. Other properties will be picked up too, plus you're not even guaranteed it'll go in ascending numeric order!

Comment: I see. So the for loop using array index is what I really want here. Thanks for the tip about ascending numeric order as well.

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake in for each loop. `date` is index of `dates`. You should write: `dates[date].beginDate`.

Answer (score 0):

When using a for..in loop, the variable gets assigned the key, not the value!

```
for (date in dates) {
    alert('after: ' + dates[date].beginDate ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for ... in` doesn't work like that with arrays, you can use a regular `for` like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bwhitney/ZDHp4/1/

Reference: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)